# Internet Explorer Javascript SCRIPT5007 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, null

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON(window.upperSlashes+"ajax.php", {some data here}, function(result)
{
    if(result["error"] != null){return alert(result["error"]);}
}
```

It works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome. but IE gives this stupid error:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'error': object is null or undefined

Ajax response --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y20b.jpg

Already put this into the header --> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Tried this one too --> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

Tried $.ajax instead of $.getJSON but it didn't fix.

Comment: What is `window.upperSlashes`?

Comment: The error isn't stupid. It's just telling you that the value of `result` is `null`. There's some problem with calling the `ajax.php` script.

Comment: @PM77-1 Internet Explorer 9

Comment: @Barmar I use URL rewriting. It determines the location of ajax.php. It is a string like "../../../"

Comment: Try removing the `!= null`, this get's odd sometimes and I have success without it, checking for existence.

Comment: @rfornal How can that fix it? The error is happening during the evaluation of `result["error"]`.

Comment: @Barmar Firefox and Chrome calls the script with no errors. There's nothing wrong with directory I think.

Comment: @rfornal Already tried but didn't work.

Comment: Can you look in the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what response the AJAX is sending?

Comment: Maybe turn it around and check against null and undefined ... the error could be in the return when trying to evaluate the alert with and undefined value.

Comment: @Barmar Response --> http://i.imgur.com/yNJTX8H.jpg

Comment: @rfornal But report["error"] is null. The alert function shouldn't be executed.

Comment: I just built a fiddle that seems to show this concept working in IE 8, 9, and edge ... **http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/rxhzL58x/**; ... did I miss something?

Comment: @rfornal Your code works as perfectly as it should do. But my code isn't wrong too. It works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I tried ajax function instead of getJson. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this:

```
header('Content-type:text/json; charset=utf8');
```

to this:

```
header('Content-type:text/json');
```

and the error gone away! It is fixed.